# "Proceed Anyway" using javascript click on "not trusted" SSL certificates

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, ssl-certificate

Is it possible to .click() "Proceed anyway" using javascript when **The site's security certificate is not trusted!** page comes up?  I'm trying to automate some tests that work in both our production environment as well as the dev/qa environment.  The problem I'm running into is in the dev environment, the certificate is for the wrong subdomain.

I've read that I could import the certificates but I'm looking for something that can either be written into the test or written as a Chrome Extension.  That way it would be limited to only the few subdomains that we trust but nothing outside.  I'm leaning towards an extension since manifest.json makes it so easy to restrict the domains you allow.

I need a suggestion on how to call a click on what I'm assuming is a button element containing the text **Proceed anyway**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.  The whole point is that the browser wants the user's decision on whether to trust the page

Comment: Right, you shouldn't be able to do that.  If you DO figure out how to do it, please report your method so it can be blocked in future browsers.

Comment: We have a WatiN method to do this in IE for our automated tests but I haven't found a way to do it in Chrome.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: get a valid cert, or trust the cert authority that created your self signed cert.